# Suspend and hibernate mode doesnt work on my laptop

Tags: suspend, asus, hibernate

When I try to run suspend or hibernate mode it's just shutdown my laptop. I've tried to pm-suspend and pm-hibernate commands but result the same.

laptop inf:

nvidia 940M

ASUS - N551JB

4.8.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu

x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Asus laptop (motherboard: ASUS N501JW).Turned out to be a motherboard software problem and got fixed after a bios/uefi update to latest version available.

The flashing program I used was the one that came on windows. It have auto detecting and downloading of new updates. For your specific model, [**this**](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/N551JB/HelpDesk_Download/) is your drivers page. BIOS-Utilities are the Windows executable, while BIOS are the actual files to flash.

However, I have no experience in trying a flashing process outside of using windows' exes that OEMs distribute.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my Lenovo laptop running Linux mint 17.

Please update your kernel with the latest one. It will solve your problem.
Follow [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) to update the kernel.

Comment: I change kernal and suspend/hibernate still doesnt work. Linux N551JB 4.11.0-999-lowlatency #201704042201 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 5 02:09:45 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

There may be one of the following problems

1. Check your swap partition size using command

   `# free -m`

   The swap partition size should be greater than physical memory for the 
   hibernation to work correctly.
2. Check hibernate logs it may tell you the problem.

   `tail /var/log/pm-suspend.log`
3. Add `resume=/dev/your-swap-partition` (of for UEFI systems `resume=UUID=<partition UUID>`) to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in `/etc/default/grub`

   Regenerate your grub.conf with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` 
   (or for UEFI systems: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`)

   Reboot -> Hibernate -> Resume. See if it works or not.

Answer (score -1):

You should update BIOS with the latest firmware by using WinFlash tool.
It was a solution for me, when I encountered the same problem with the sleep mode was not working properly on my Asus N501jw.

Comment: There are more complete answers posted 4 years ago.